# Table equivalent of the word booth?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I was watching one TV show, and in one episode, the protoganist were having food at an establishment.

They used the word booth to describe where they were sitting, instead of chair.

I would like to know if there is a difference between the word chair and booth?

Also, what is the 'booth' equivalent to the word table. For e.g. just like there is equivalency between booth and chair, is there an equivalent word for table?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=restaurant+booth&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiww_u6-eH3AhUph_0HHaKuAEMQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=restaurant+booth&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6BAgjECc6BAgAEEM6BggAEAcQHlCdC1jQKmDfL2gAcAB4AIABY4gB8AeSAQIxMpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=bC2BYrDdJqmO9u8Pot2CmAQ&bih=562&biw=1126

Answer (score 6):

Where I live (USA), a *booth* corresponds to this definition:

[AHD *booth*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=booth)
2. A seating area in a restaurant with a table and seats whose high backs serve as partitions.

[M-W *booth*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/booth)
2 c. : an enclosed seating area (as in a restaurant) consisting typically of a table placed between two high-backed benches

In that environment, a *table* is just a table, with independent chairs around it.

Comment: Note that to serve as a partitions, the seats are attached, not individual, and often fixed to the floor.

Comment: @Mary Yes, and often, but not always, one end of each bench is fixed to a wall, making a u-shaped space with the table in the middle.